# What does it mean to say that a point at infinity is mapped to $0$?

Tags: transformation, projective-geometry, projective-space

We have a transformation of projective 2-space, which my lecture notes assert map the point at infinity is mapped to $0$. Whilst I intuitively understand why this is the case, I am not sure how to formalize this.

My difficulty stems from the fact that the transformation is given in terms of affine coordinate. Specifically, we are working over $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$, and the birational transformation (in affine coordinates) is given by

$$
x' = -\frac{x}y, \quad y' = -\frac1y
$$

My lecture notes asserts that this maps the projective point at infinity, $(0;1;0)$ to the affine origin. Similarly, we would expect the affine point $(a, 0)$ to be mapped to the point at infinity, $(a; 1; 0)$. Whilst I can intuitively see why this is the case (at the level of "$1/\infty = 0$"), I want to formalize this. However, I'm not sure how to convert the above transformation into one involving projective coordinates so that I can show this algebraically.

---

*What I have tried so far*: (Disclaimer, I am studying this as part of a course on elliptic curves, but have not studied any projective geometry on its own prior to this.)

It seems reasonable to replace $x$ with $X/Z$ and $x'$ with $X'/Z'$ in the equations for the transformations above (and similarly for $y$ and $y'$). Doing this and then rearranging gives

$$
X'Y = -XZ', \quad YY' = - ZZ'
$$

This seems to show that $(0;1;0)$ maps to $(0;0;1)$, but doesn't seem to give a well defined map if $Y=0$ (e.g. for the point $(a;0;1)$, all we can deduce is that $Z' = 0$; on the other hand, intuitively, this point should map to $(a; 1; 0)$).

Is this is the right projective transformation to extend the affine transformation given above? Is this even the right way to go about it?

Comment: The full projective transformation is $(X; Y; Z) \mapsto (X; Z; -Y)$. You can check that this matches your transformation in the affine case by setting $Z=1$. Geometrically, if we think of $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ as lines through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we usually take the intersection with the plane $Z=1$ as the affine coordinates. Under this transformation, we instead take use the plane $Y = -1$. If I have time I will add a full answer with a better explanation of the geometric intuition.